# How to run custom task after gradle assemble command

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Actually I have these lines as part of my build.gradle file (using gradle 7.3.3)

```
processResources {
    dependsOn "buildAngular"
}


task buildAngular(type: Exec) {
...
```

my task "buildAngular" runs automaticly on `./gradlew assemble` its perfect and exactly what I want.  But it runs on `./gradlew test` too.

How I can make it run only on `./gradlew assemble`?

Comment: Since tests require a complete runtime classpath and since `processResources` produces parts of that classpath, it wouldn’t make sense to not run it when `test` is run. Why is `buildAngular` a dependency of `processResources`? Did you only do that to make it run on `./gradlew assemble`?

Comment: " Did you only do that to make it run on ./gradlew assemble?"  Yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment on the question:

> Since tests require a complete runtime classpath and since `processResources` produces parts of that classpath, it wouldn’t make sense to not run it when `test` is run.

If you only want to run `buildAngular` as part of `assemble`, then simply make the former a dependency of the latter:

```groovy
assemble {
    dependsOn 'buildAngular'
}
```